# Annotate ggplot2 across both axis: text keeps changing position

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I am trying to annotate both axes of my plot with some text, but when I do that, I am unable to position the text as I would like. By adding new text on one axis, the text on the other axis gets misplaced.

How to deal with that?

Here is an example to illustrate my issue:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(50, 5, 2)
y <- x + 1 + rnorm(50)
data <- cbind.data.frame(x,y)

#Create a plot in which I annotate in one axis (it works great)

plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x, y))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=median(data$x, na.rm = T), color = 'red') +
  geom_vline(xintercept=median(data$y, na.rm = T), color = 'red') +
  labs(y="Label y", x = "Label x") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, na.rm = TRUE, fullrange= TRUE,
              aes(group=1),colour="black") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 30, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 30, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  annotate("text", x = 9, y = -3, label = "Helpful Text2") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = -3, label = "Helpful Text1") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 15), clip = "off")

#Trying to add annotation to the second axis (it alters the axis of the plot, thereby misplacing the annotation I have done prior)
plot + annotate("text", x = 0, y = 8.5, label = "Helpful Text3", angle = 90) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 2, label = "Helpful Text4", angle = 90) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 9), clip = "off")
```

Ideas?

Comment: It's not that adding text changes the position, it is that you are changing your coordinates the second time around. Since your annotations are plotted in terms of your plot's coordinate system, your text will "move" when you change coordinates. Remove the second `coord_cartesian` call if you want the first text to stay where it is.

Comment: The issue is that if I do that, than I cannot place the text that goes on the y axis outside the plot. In other words, if I add this to the plot, I still have a problem: plot + annotate("text", x = 0, y = 12, label = "Helpful Text3", angle = 90) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 3, label = "Helpful Text4", angle = 90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```r
plot + annotate("text", x = -1, y = 14, label = "Helpful Text3", angle = 90) +
  annotate("text", x = -1, y = 0, label = "Helpful Text4", angle = 90) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 15), xlim = c(0, 10), clip = "off")
```

[image]

Just make sure you set `fullrange = FALSE` in `geom_smooth` when defining your plot.